# How to initialize a class stored in a variable of an abstract class?

Tags: typescript, constructor, abstract-class, factory

I am working on a TypeScript project for fun and ran into an interesting situation where I am unable to instantiate a reference to a class, likely because TypeScript assumes it is an *instance* of a class.

```
const programClass: Program = this.fetchProgram(programName) as Program
```

`fetchProgram` is returning a `program` class from a *map* where each program has been loaded in dynamically from files.

*Sample of how the map is created:*

```
const programPath = "../../../programs"
const programFiles = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, programPath))

programFiles.forEach(file => {
  file = path.join(__dirname, programPath, file)
  const cmdClass = require(file).default
  const command = new cmdClass() as Program
  this.commands.set(command.alias, command)
})
```

Each *"program"* is a file that exports a class which extends the abstract class `program`.

*Sample program:*

```
export default class ProgramEcho extends Program {
  alias = "echo"
  constructor(options: ProgramOptions) {
    super(options)
    console.log(`DEBUG: Program Instantiated: Echo`)
  }
}
```

Now,
Back to the first code snippet. This is indeed being treated as an instance of `Program`, when truly I need it to be a constructable class of some type which extends Program.

```
const programClass: Program = this.fetchProgram(programName) as Program
const program = new programClass()
```

*error:*

```
const programClass: Program
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'Program' has no construct signatures.ts(2351)
```

It seems like you could do a simple factory pattern where the abstract class `program` has a function called `create` which returns a new `Program`, but you can not return an instance of an abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've observed, the type `Program` refers to an instance of the `Program` class.  What you want is a constructor that can create a `Program` instance.  Assuming that all of your `Program` subclasses take the same constructor arguments, the type that you want is:

```
type ProgramConstructor = new (options: ProgramOptions) => Program;
```

This allows you to create an instance:

```
const programClass: ProgramConstructor = this.fetchProgram(programName) as ProgramConstructor;
const options: ProgramOptions = ??? // not sure where this comes from
const program = new programClass(options);
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/rNdKMw)